# Pythagorean Law for Inner Product Spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

> **The Pythagorean Law:** if **u** and **v** are orthogonal vectors in an
>   inner product space $V$, then
>
> $||$**u**$+$**v**$||^2 = ||$**u**$||^2+||$**v**$||^2$
>
> **Proof:**
>
> 1. $||$**u**$+$**v**$||^2 = <$**u**$+$**v**$,  $**u**$+$**v**$>$
> 2. $||$**u**$+$**v**$||^2 = <$**u**$,  $**u**$> +
>    2<$**u**$,$**v**$>+<$**v**$,  $**v**$>$
> 3. $||$**u**$+$**v**$||^2 = ||$**u**$||^2+||$**v**$||^2$

I believe part 1 is obtained by: 
$||$**u**$+$**v**$||^2 = (\sqrt{<u+v,  u+v>})^2 = {<u+v,  u+v>}$

What happens from part 1 to part 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linearity happens!

Remember from the definition of an inner product that $\langle u+v,w \rangle = \langle u,w \rangle + \langle v,w \rangle$ and $\langle u,v+w \rangle = \langle u,v \rangle + \langle u,w \rangle$. Applying this fact gives you the expression required.

Answer (score 1):

You are just using the fact that the internal product is bilinear.

In other words:

$<a+b,c> = <a,c>  + <b,c>$

Etc.